# Prevent array decaying to ** from *[N]

Tags: c++

I have declared my array like this:

```
FT_Interface<4096> *to_make_ft[3] = { /* initialization with existing objects */ };
```

my interface is declared like this:

```
template<cyg_ucount32 S, int N>
class FT_Thread {
  FT_Thread(FT_Interface<S> *entry[N]){}
};
```

And i call it (as expected with):

```
FT_Thread<4096, 3> ft(to_make_ft);
```

Yet it complains that the pointer has decayed.

`ecos/install/include/ft/thread.hxx:70: error: incompatible types in assignment of ‘FT_Interface<4096u>**’ to ‘FT_Interface<4096u>* [3]’`

Is there any way to prevent this from happening?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need

```
FT_Thread(FT_Interface<S>* (&entry)[N]){}
//             note these  ^^-----^
```

With that, you get a reference to the array.

---

**Edit**: Of course, if you want a pointer to the array, you can have just that:

```
FT_Thread(FT_Interface<S>* (*entry)[N]){}
```

Though you need to call it with `FT_Thread<4096,3> ft(&to_make_ft)`.

Comment: Ah, yes, this was it. @Xeo is there a way to get a copy of the address of the array?

Comment: @RedX: You can always use the & operator to get a pointer: `FT_Interface<S>* (*ptr_to_entry)[N] = &entry;`

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is right, but try changing

```
FT_Thread(FT_Interface<S> *entry[N]){}
```

to

```
FT_Thread(FT_Interface<S> (*entry[N])){}
```

I have a feeling that the compiler thinks that the * refers to the FT_Interface rather than the entry.